# FireFox - Are all preferences in about:config located in .js files?

Tags: firefox, configuration, mozilla, preferences

I am writing a script to grab some Firefox settings, however it looks like some preferences are not within Firefox's various .js files.

The preferences I am referring to are the preferences in about:config (such as network.http.max-connections). The .js file I am mainly referring to is prefs.js.

So my question is: Are all preferences shown in about:config hidden in some .js file?

Thanks!
Jonathan

Answer (score 1):

http://www.mozilla.org/unix/customizing.html#prefs

> Normal prefs are kept in prefs.js in the user's profile directory

I'm going to guess that prefs with `default` settings aren't written to the file.

You might take a look at the [Preferential](http://preferential.mozdev.org/index.html) addon documentation.

Comment: Yeah, the default settings aren't held in the prefs.js file. I was hoping there was some file I was missing that kept all the default settings. 

When I edit anything in about:config, the preference will appear in user.js, so they aren't held on file until then.

As for Preferential, it looks like it became obsolete after about:config came out.

Comment: Whoops, didn't notice it was that old. Their documentation might still be helpful, though.

Comment: Yeah. I'm planning to swim through the source code to see if/how they grab all the preferences. If they found some alternative way of getting everything, then that will solve my problem in no time :) Maybe I will install Firefox 2 somewhere and give it a go.

Thanks for the lead!

Answer (score 0):

What are you actually trying to do?

prefs.js in the user profile stores the modified preferences.

The default values are stored in <app dir>/defaults/preferences/* and in similar directories in every installed extension. Not all preferences that have effect on the core application are listed in the `defaults` files. Those that are not, are not listed in about:config until the user adds add them.

From within Firefox getting the list of preferences that have user-set or default value is easily done via the pref API, in particular [nsIPrefBranch](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/nsIPrefBranch).

[edit] see also https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Code_snippets/Preferences#Default_preferences